# What is Weka's InfoGainAttributeEval formula for evaluating Entropy with continuous values?

Tags: machine-learning, formula, weka, entropy, information-gain

I'm using Weka's attribute selection function for Information Gain and I'm trying to figure out what the specific formula Weka uses when dealing with continuous data.

I understand the usual formula for Entropy is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZ2XF.png) for when the values in the data are discrete. I understand that when dealing with continuous data one can either use Differential Entropy or discretize the values. I've tried looking at Weka's explanation to [InfoGainAttributeEval](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/attributeSelection/InfoGainAttributeEval.html) and have looking through so many other references, but can't find anything.

Maybe its just me, but would anyone know how Weka implements this case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked the author Mark Hall and he said:

> It uses the supervised MDL-based discretization method of Fayad and
>   Irani. See the javadocs:
>   http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.stable-3-8/weka/attributeSelection/InfoGainAttributeEval.html

Also you can see this link for the discretization method:

http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.stable-3-8/weka/filters/supervised/attribute/Discretize.html

Comment: This might be a little late, but thank you very much for the information and the effort! Did not see the Discretize function.